# can't make a programm that counts nonterminal nodes in a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, spyder

This is a syntactic tree and it looks like this in the form of code

**[image: ('S', [('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Katze')]), ('VP', [('V', 'jagt'), ('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Vögel')])])])]**

My program is supposed to count the number of non-terminal nodes on that tree. The idea is that every tree is a 2 tuple. On the first position stands the mother node as a string and on the second position stands either a string if there is a terminal node or a list with daughter trees of the mother node. They are recursive. **The program should count the number of nonterminal nodes**.
so the result should just be a number of nonterminal nodes, e.g. 9.

So far as I have understood, I should do this using recursion. But there are some things that I fail to do correctly to make my programm work. My code is:

```
tuple_list = []
second_tuple_elements = [a_tuple[1] for a_tuple in tuple_list]
print(second_tuple_elements)
def nonterminal(count):

    if second_tuple_elements == type(""):

        return 1

    if second_tuple_elements == type([]):
        for element in list:
            if element == type (""):
                return 1
            nonterminal = second_tuple_elements + element
```

Comment: You say you want to do it with recursion, but you did not used any recursion in your code. Also, a clarification question: does second element in tuple is a list of tuples or a list of strings of terminals?. It will be easier if you provide an example input in `tuple_list`, so we can work on your example

Comment: thank you for your feedback, i get so confused I thought this was a recursion what I was doing. the second element is a list of strings.
the example looks like this:
print(node_count(('S', [('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Katze')]), ('VP', [('V', 'jagt'), ('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Vögel')])])])))
and the result should be 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
def count_nodes(tree):
    count = 0

    if isinstance(tree, str):
        return 0
    node, rest = tree 
    count +=1 
    for subtree in rest: 
        count += count_nodes(subtree)

    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no recursive call in your program -

```py
def node_count(node):
  mother, children = node       # get parts of node tuple
  if isinstance(children, str): # mother of terminal node
    return 1                    # return 1 to count this mother
  else:                         # mother of non-terminal node
    return 1 + \                # return 1 plus...
      sum(node_count(x) for x in children) # the sum of each child node_count 

my_tree = \
  ('S', [('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Katze')]), ('VP', [('V', 'jagt'), ('NP', [('ART', 'die'), ('N', 'Vögel')])])])

print(node_count(my_tree))
# 9
```